# Why does $t = \frac ds$ and not $\frac sd$? (from $ s = \frac dt$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I'm stupid so I don't understand why I get

$t =\frac sd$

when I isolate $t$ (time) in the speed formula $s =\frac dt$ when its actually

$t =\frac ds$

I've gotten so many answers wrong because of my stupidity and I don't understand why it's wrong.

Here's what I do:

> $s = \frac dt \to s = \frac dt \bullet\frac1d \to \frac 1d\bullet s = \frac1t \to \frac sd = t$

I'm just a stressed highschool student so please have some patients with me. I'm not particularly the best at math.

Comment: Last operation: why do you replace $\tfrac 1t$ by $t$?

Comment: @Arthur The answer to that lies in the first two words of my question

Comment: @Otaku Just because you haven't grokked something yet, that doesn't mean you're stupid. It just means that you haven't gotten it yet.

Comment: Another problem: going from the first equality to the second, you have to multiply **both** sides by $\frac{1}{d}$, not just the right-hand side, although it has miraculously reappeared in the third equality (which is correct). The fourth equality is wrong as both @amsmath in a comment and the answer point out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are okay until the last step.  So start like you would but not your last step:

> $$s = \frac dt \\ \to s \bullet\frac1d = \frac dt \bullet\frac1d \\ \to \frac 1d\bullet s = \frac1t \\ \to \frac{s}{d} = \frac{1}{t}$$

From here, you solved for $1/t$, **not** for $t$.  To solve for $t$, reciprocate both sides of the equal sign in the last step above:
$$ \frac{s}{d} = \frac{1}{t} \\ \to \frac{d}{s} = t $$

Comment: The $\cdot \frac1d$ in line two isn't really that good without a counterpart on the left-hand side. That counterpart first appears on line 3.

Comment: @Arthur good catch..

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply by $1/d$, you have done only for RHS. If you multiply also by $1/d$ the LHS, you have: $\frac{s}{d}=\frac{1}{t}$. So raising to the :$-1$ power you obtain: $t=\frac{d}{s}$?